# Extract date, day, time in single columns out of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert the dataframe so that I have one column with "Day", one with "date", one with "time"?
I tried to slide bit can't get the correct output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datum': ["Samstag, 12.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr", "Samstag, 19.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 18:30 Uhr", "Samstag, 26.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr"], 
                   'Begegnungen': ["TTSV SCHOTT Mainz  - Borussia Dortmund", "VfL Bochum  -  Borussia Dortmund",  "Freiburg  -  Borussia Dortmund"]}) 

def custom_slice(full_string, start_index, end_index):
    return full_string[start_index:end_index]

# Define the start and end indices for the slicing
start_index = 5
end_index = 10

# Apply the custom slicing function to the 'TextColumn' and create a new column 'SlicedColumn'
df['SlicedColumn'] = df['Datum'].apply(lambda x: custom_slice(x, start_index, end_index))

# Display the DataFrame with the sliced column
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression pattern to extract date time.

```
pat = r'(\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}).*?(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)'
df[['date', 'time']] = df['Datum'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
```

---

```
                                    Datum                             Begegnungen        date   time
0  Samstag, 12.08.2023Ansto├â um 15:30 Uhr  TTSV SCHOTT Mainz  - Borussia Dortmund  12.08.2023  15:30
1  Samstag, 19.08.2023Ansto├â um 18:30 Uhr        VfL Bochum  -  Borussia Dortmund  19.08.2023  18:30
2  Samstag, 26.08.2023Ansto├â um 15:30 Uhr          Freiburg  -  Borussia Dortmund  26.08.2023  15:30
```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object :(

Answer (score 0):

The code from @Shubhab Sharma works for your sample. The TypeError may have to do with rows that do not contain a string, e.g. missing values.

Expanding on the previous answer you could do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datum': ["Samstag, 12.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr", 
                             "Samstag, 19.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 18:30 Uhr", 
                             "Samstag, 26.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr"], 
                    'Begegnungen': ["TTSV SCHOTT Mainz  - Borussia Dortmund", 
                                    "VfL Bochum  -  Borussia Dortmund",  
                                    "Freiburg  -  Borussia Dortmund"]}) 

# remove all rows with NaN in column 'Datum' to avoid TypeErrors
df.dropna(subset=['Datum'], inplace=True)

# regex as suggested by @Shubham Sharma
pat = r'(\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}).*?(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)'
df[['date', 'time']] = df['Datum'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)

# convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
# extract day of week
df["day"] = df["date"].dt.weekday
display(df)
```

Output

```
    Datum   Begegnungen date    time    day
0   Samstag, 12.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr TTSV SCHOTT Mainz - Borussia Dortmund   2023-08-12  15:30   5
1   Samstag, 19.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 18:30 Uhr VfL Bochum - Borussia Dortmund  2023-08-19  18:30   5
2   Samstag, 26.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr Freiburg - Borussia Dortmund    2023-08-26  15:30   5
```

To further extract the name of the weekday:

```
import calendar
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

DAY_NAMES = [calendar.day_name[x] for x in range(0,7)]
df["day_name"] = df["day"].apply(lambda x: DAY_NAMES[x])
display(df)
```

Output

```
Datum   Begegnungen date    time    day day_name
0   Samstag, 12.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr TTSV SCHOTT Mainz - Borussia Dortmund   2023-08-12  15:30   5   Samstag
1   Samstag, 19.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 18:30 Uhr VfL Bochum - Borussia Dortmund  2023-08-19  18:30   5   Samstag
2   Samstag, 26.08.2023AnstoÃŸ um 15:30 Uhr Freiburg - Borussia Dortmund    2023-08-26  15:30   5   Samstag
```